# What must be done to use the value of a reference type as a dictionary key?

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary, gethashcode

Suppose I have a class `T` that I want to use as a key in a `Dictionary<T,U>` collection.

What must I implement in `T` so that these keys are based on values of `T` rather than `T` references?

I'm hoping it's just `GetHashCode()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You must implement GetHashCode() and Equals().

Dictionary is a Hashtable below the covers, so you might want to read this: [Pitfalls Of Equals/GetHashCode – How Does A Hash Table Work?](https://web.archive.org/web/20200927174248/http://geekswithblogs.net/akraus1/archive/2010/02/28/138234.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

If you don't pass any `IEqualityComparer<T>` in the dictionary constructor, it will use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` which is defined by MSDN as :

> The Default property checks whether
>   type T implements the System.IEquatable(Of T)
>   interface and, if so, returns an
>   EqualityComparer(Of T) that
>   uses that implementation. Otherwise,
>   it returns an EqualityComparer(Of T) that uses the overrides of
>   Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.

So implementing `IEquatable<T>` would be my choice (if you implement it it also makes sense to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` anyway).

Comment: I wouldn't recommend having any inheritable type implement IEquatable<T>, since bad things will happen if a derived type overrides Object.Equals(Object) and/or Object.GetHashCode(Object) and the implementation of IEquatable<T> doesn't call those overrides; since casting to Object to call those overrides would defeat any advantage obtained from using the generic interface, there's really no point to implementing it.

Answer (score 3):

*Either* implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` *or* create an appropriate [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) which has the right form of equality matching for your map.

I rather like the `IEqualityComparer<T>` route: in many cases there isn't one obviously-right form of equality - you want to treat objects as equal in different ways depending on the situation. In that case, a custom equality comparer is just what you need. Of course, if there *is* a natural equality operation, it makes sense to implement `IEquatable<T>` in the type itself... if you can. (Another benefit of `IEqualityComparer<T>` is that you can implement it for types you have no control over.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to override [`Equals(object obj)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx).  It is always expected that you implement `GetHashCode` when you modify `Equals`.  Read this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336aedhh.aspx) at MSDN.